# Java HashSet is allowing duplicates

Tags: java, hashset

I need to create an `ID` based on a 15x15 matrix values and since it is not possible to create an integer of size 15, I tried the following reasoning to create an `ID` of type `double`:

First I create a `String` with the values of the cells and while I do this, I look for the cell that has a value of `0`. When I find I enter a dot "." in the `String`. Then I convert my `String` to `BigDecilmal` and the method I call `doubleValue ()`.

```
   public double generateId() {
        String sid = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.matrix[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[1].length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j].equals("0")) {
                    sid += ".";
                } else {
                    sid += matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ID: " + new BigDecimal(sid).doubleValue());
        return new BigDecimal(sid).doubleValue();
    }
```

I checked and the generated IDs are uniques.

Based on this, I tried to implement `HashCode()` as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    long bits = doubleToLongBits(id);
    int hash = (int) (bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
    System.out.println("hash: " + hash);
    return hash;
}
```

But my HashSet continues with duplicate values :(
Does anyone have a suggestion about how to do this?

**~~>EDIT**

Sate class:

```
   public class State {

    public double id;
    public String[][] matrix;

    public State() {

    }

    public State(String[][] matrix) {
        this.matrix = createMatrix(matrix);//is created from a existing matrix
        this.id = generateId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((other == null) || !(other instanceof State)) {
            return false;
        }
        return ((State) other).getId().equals(this.getId()) && ((State) other).getId() == this.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        long bits = doubleToLongBits(id);
        int hash = (int) (bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
        System.out.println("hash: " + hash);
        return hash;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Hashcode: " + this.hashCode();
    }

    public Double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String[][] getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    public void setMatrix(String[][] matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    public double generateId() {
        String sid = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.matrix[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[1].length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j].equals("0")) {
                    sid += ".";
                } else {
                    sid += matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ID: " + new BigDecimal(sid).doubleValue());
        return new BigDecimal(sid).doubleValue();

    }

    private String[][] createMatrix(String[][] matriz) {
        String[][] copia = new String[matriz[0].length][matriz[1].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < copia[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < copia[1].length; j++) {
                copia[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
        return copia;
    }
```

Comment: One problem: `if (matrix[i][j] == "0") {`. You **must** use `.equals(...)` if it's a String

Comment: Why not use `BigInteger` ?

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Why not use `long` which allows 18 digits?

Comment: The double will only keep the top 15 digits. If your matrix is large enough, most of the matrix will be ignored.

Comment: How are you implementing `equals()`? If you're getting duplicates in a `Set` then you have a problem there too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels omg you're right, I will edit the question because I still getting duplicates

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried use Long but I was receiving the NumberFormatException without reason, so I deduced that the number was too big

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle I edited the question with my equals method

Comment: @Éowyn What is the return type of `State.getId()`? Actually, edit your question to include the full source code of the `State` class.

Comment: @Progman I edited the question :)

Comment: @Éowyn Remove the `==` check in your `equals()` method.

Comment: If the number is too big for `long` it has more than 18 digits of precision, but `double` only have about 15 which means all the digits after that are likely to be silently dropped meaning you will only get unique matrix if the first values are different, and the rest don't matter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the problem is that exists numbers greater than 9, so I'm getting more than 18 :( I  just realized it now

Comment: @Progman I did it, but I'm still gettig duplicates

Comment: @Éowyn Okay, please edit your question to include a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows that you get duplicates when you run the MVCE.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is in the equals method,

you have to remove the last part:

```
 && ((State) other).getId() == this.getId();
```

you are checking if the Boolean has the same reference, but they don't need the reference to be equal, it's enough that there value is equal

Comment: Or make the `getId()`ethod return `double`, since it is returning a primitive field anyway, and ditch the `equals` check

Answer (score -1):

I would propose using the built-in methods of the `Arrays` class to generate a hashCode and test for equality:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return Arrays.deepHashCode(matrix);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ((other == null) || !(other instanceof State)) {
        return false;
    }
   State s = (State)other;
   return Arrays.deepEquals(matrix, s.matrix);
}
```